# How do I calculate for the power series and convergence radius $R\in \left [ 0,\infty \right ]$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I calculate for the power series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^ki}{\sqrt{k}}\left (\frac{z}{2} \right )^k$ the development point $ z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ and convergence radius $R\in \left [ 0,\infty \right ]$?

Comment: What is $i$ here?

Comment: if $i$ is just a constant then it can be pulled out, and then group the terms with exponent $k$ into $\left(\frac{3z}{2}\right)^k$, and that can be replaced by some other variable $w$. Then the sum is just $\sum \frac{w^k}{\sqrt{k}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help: By the ratio test, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left\vert\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}\right\vert=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left\vert\dfrac{\frac{3^{k+1}i}{\sqrt{k+1}}\left (\frac{z}{2} \right )^{k+1}}{\frac{3^ki}{\sqrt{k}}\left (\frac{z}{2} \right )^k}\right\vert=\lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{3\cdot\left\vert\frac{z}{2}\right\vert\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\frac{3}{2}\vert z\vert<1\implies \vert z\vert<\frac{2}{3}$$